# Error en código de aplicación para: Insertar una imagen

Tags: python, pyqt5

cuando intento ejecutar esta aplicación: se ejecuta pero cuando intento "Insertar la imagen" se cierra. ¿Cuál es el error en el código? El problema debería ser una mezcla entre sintaxis o codigo pyqt4 y pyqt5 pero no logro solucionarlo. No se si me faltó importar alguna clase, o si hay algun problema con la importacion de los recursos o imagenes utilizadas en la aplicación.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class MyForm(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__()
    uic.loadUi("ejemplo_menu.ui", self)

    self.barra_menus = self.menuBar()
    self.widget_central = self.centralWidget()
    self.barra_estado = self.statusBar()

    self.ins_imagen.triggered.connect(self.saca_imagen)
    self.bor_imagen.triggered.connect(self.borra_imagen)


def saca_imagen(self):
    mi_imagen = QPixmap("reina_tréboles.jpeg");
    mi_etiqueta = QLabel()
    mi_etiqueta.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    mi_etiqueta.setPixmap(mi_imagen)
    self.setCentralWidget(mi_etiqueta)
    self.barra_estado.showMessage("La imagen ha sido representada en pantalla")


def borra_imagen(self):
    etiqueta_central = self.centralWidget()
    if type(etiqueta_central) == QLabel and etiqueta_central.pixmap() != None:
        etiqueta_central.clear()
        self.barra_estado.showMessage("La imagen se ha eliminado de la pantalla")
    else:
        self.barra_estado.showMessage("No hay imagen en pantalla para eliminar")



if __name__=="__main__":
   app=QApplication(sys.argv)
   myapp=MyForm()
   myapp.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: te falta importar : from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap sino no podrás usarla y en la declaración de Qlabel  ¿dónde estará? minimo Qlabel(self)

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! con eso que me dijiste más otros detalles que me faltaban pude lograr el resultado que buscaba.

Comment: Si querés podés hacer una auto respuesta ,así, si a otros les gusta te puntuan